# What is the structure of this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement

> He alleges another £1m had gone on material purchases based on projections of Arcadia orders he was told were coming down the line.

I can't understand the meaning of this sentences.This sentence is seems simple sentence because there is no connector. As I know a simple sentence has one clause , that's mean one subject and one finite verb but here I can see more than one clause and more than subject and verb came here.